# Hide SwiftUI NavigationLink's (or Button's) hover- focus style on tvOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, tvos

I have a LazyVGrid with a bunch of NavigationLinks in it. For a nice look & feel I would like to set the `.buttonStyle(.card)` on them, so I get the hover and 'glimmering' effect for free.

But the drawback is that it also adds a light background to the view. Here's a quick example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let items = 1 ... 10

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200))], spacing: 16) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Item: \(item)")) {
                        ItemView(item: item)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.card)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    let item: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.yellow)
                .strokeBorder(.blue, lineWidth: 8)
                .frame(height: 100)

            Text("Item \(item)")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image: Example with added background colors]

How can I prevent this from happening? Using `.hoverEffect(..)` and `.focusEffect(..)` doesn't really help, but maybe I'm approaching it all wrong...

Answer (score 0):

[hoverEffectDisabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/hovereffectdisabled(_:)?changes=_7) did the trick for me.

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Item: \(item)")) {
    ItemView(item: item)
}
.hoverEffectDisabled(true)
```